# SQL join on many queries

Tags: sql, plsql, join

I have a table with a structure such as table(PK, a, b, c, d, e, f, g).

And I have many queries that I want to join:

```
select PK, sum(c) where...

JOIN

select PK, sum(e) where...

JOIN

select PK, sum(g) where ...

JOIN

 select PK,a,b,d,f
```

Every sum(c|e|g) is actually a

```
select sum(c|e|g) from .... where...
```

because there are many conditions involved (not all c|e|g's must be added)

Is this the best way to do it? I was suggested to write it in PL / SQL, which I would have to learn. If its the way to go, i'll do it, but im not sure whats wrong with the solution shown above.

## Edit

Im pretty sure its a Join. Here's what I want.

I need to get a result set in the form:

```
PK, a,b,COMPLEX_SUM_ON_C,d,COMPLEX_SUM_ON_D,f,COMPLEX_DUM_ON_G
```

so I thought of joining many queries to get this result.

Each of the COMPLEX... is another select (select sum...). This is a very big table, and writing

```
select a,b,(select sum..),d,(select sum...),f,(select sum...)
```

will yield bad performance (so I was told to remove it)

I've edited my query above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean union?

Comment: Please show sample rows from the input table and the desired output.  As others have pointed out, it's not clear whether you want JOIN or UNION.  Also, you may have a substantial design issue with your table (depending on what the data actually looks like).

Comment: It's difficult to answer this without knowing what sort of results you're expecting to get back from this query. I suggest you have a quick look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29 to see if it really is a JOIN that you want.

Answer (score 3):

I think you mean "UNION" not "JOIN".  Whether is the best way depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

An example of a JOIN is the following:

```
Select a.col1, b.col2
FROM table1 a, table2 b
WHERE a.key = b.key;
```

which can also be written:

```
SELECT a.col1, b.col2
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b
ON a.key = b.key;
```

**Edit:**

After reading your re-edit of the original question, you can probably use a JOIN.  JOINs can be used when you have related data in more than one table, or you can specifiy the same table multiple times.  I have used both kinds with Oracle.  Here's an example of the latter kind which will hopefully help you:

```
SELECT t1.a, t1.b, t3.sum(c), t2.d, t4.sum(e), t1.f, t5.sum(g)
FROM table1 t1, table1 t2, table1 t3, table1 t4, table1 t5
WHERE  t1.a = 'hello'
AND t2.a = 'world'
AND t3.c = 10
AND t4.e = 20
AND t5.g = 100
GROUP BY t1.a, t1.b, t2.d, t1.f;
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems im not clear enough (my bad). Ive re edited my question.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a well-defined problem (yet).

Assuming PK is your primary key (i.e. unique, by definition), then

```
SELECT PK, SUM(c)
FROM tbl
GROUP BY PK
```

is **ALWAYS** the same as

```
SELECT PK, c
FROM tbl
```

So grouping (and aggregating) is relatively meaningless.

In your expected results:

```
PK, a,b,COMPLEX_SUM_ON_C,d,COMPLEX_SUM_ON_D,f,COMPLEX_DUM_ON_G
```

How are `COMPLEX_SUM_ON_C`, `COMPLEX_SUM_ON_D`, `COMPLEX_DUM_ON_G` related to PK?

We know how a, b, d, f are related to PK, because for each PK, one can identify the one and only a, b, d, f on the same row.